# How to parsing Json response to Swift objects

Tags: json, swift

Hi i am beginner for swift language and in my project i am using web services and after got response how can i parse below response to Swift object can some on help me please

### response:-

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "age": 25,
        "address": {
            "id": 1,
            "street_address": "2nd Street",
            "city": "Bakersfield",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": 93309
         }

    }
]
```

### ModelClass:-

```
class Address:NSObject{

struct Address {
    let objID: Int?
    let streetAddress: String?
    let city: String?
    let state: String?
    let postalCode: String?
}

struct User {
    let objID: Int?
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let age: Int?
    let address : Address?
   }
}
```

### ViewController:-

```
func finalResponse(response : AnyObject){

    let addressArray = response as! NSArray;
        for items in addressArray{
        }
  }
```

Comment: address is not an array. what have you tried already? what problem are you getting with what you've tried already?

Comment: i want to keep all objects in Array through for loop

Comment: are you using swift 4? Xcode 9? It's a new feature, so it will not work on older versions of swift. You would have to do the cast manually by iterating through the dictionary if not.

Comment: Also inside Address, postalCode should be an Int not String

Comment: i am not using swift 4 i am using swift 3

Comment: that's ok how can i parse it please let me know that

Comment: are you using SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 it get lot easier

**Your Model class look like this**
Key should be same as json response or make enum for changing the name

```
struct Address: Decodable {
    let objID: Int?
    let streetAddress: String?
    let city: String?
    let state: String?
    let postalCode: String?
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let objID: Int?
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let age: Int?
    let address : Address?
   }
}
```

**Your view Controller class look like this**

```
try decoder.decode([User.self], from: jsonData)
```

Comment: try decoder.decode([User.self], from: jsonData) please eleborate this code some more i am bigginer for swift

Answer (score 0):

This is olden days method in objective-c swift 1,2,3

**This is model Class**

```
class SafeJson: NSObject{

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        let firstCharacter = String(key.characters.first!).uppercased()
        let range = NSMakeRange(0,1)
        let valuex = NSString(string: key).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: firstCharacter)
   //     let valuex = key.replacingCharacters(in: range, offsetBy: 0), with: firstCharacter)
        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("set\(valuex):")
        let respond = self.responds(to: selector)
        if !respond{
            return
        }
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}


class Model:SafeJson{

       // var thumbnail_image_name: String?
        var title: String?
        var number_of_views: NSNumber?
        var channel: Channel?
        override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
            if key == "channel"{
                self.channel = Channel()
                let dictionary = value as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.channel?.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            }else{
            super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        } 
        init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
            super.init()
            setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
        }
    }

    class Channel:SafeJson{
        var name: String?
        var profile_image_name: String?

    }
```

**In your View controller class You have to pass your response to Model.init** it automatically save to model

***But in swift 4 setValueForKey is depricated*** 
You have to use decodable for it

Answer (score 0):

warning, did not get to test it so let me know for any warnings and will adjust

For Swift3

```
func finalResponse(response : AnyObject){

    var result: [Address] = []
    let json = response as! [String:AnyObject]
            // ITERATE THROUGH THE ARRAY OF DICTIONARIES
        for item in json {
          // a WILL BE THE MAIN OBJECT YOU'RE CREATING
            var a = Adress()
            a.objID = item["id"] as! Int
                 .....
                 // REPEAT FOR EVERY ELEMENT UNTIL YOU REACH NEXT SUBCLASS
                 .....
            // CREATE A NEW DICTIONARY FOR THE SUBCLASS Address
            var b = item["address"] as! Dictionary<String, String>
            a.address.objID = b["id"] as! Int

            // IF YOU DON'T WANT TO CREATE var b YOU CAN WRITE
            // a.address.objID = a["address"]["id"]     INSTEAD

            // ADD YOUR OBJECT TO RESULT
            result.append(a)
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Herr is the code to parse data from your JSON data. Create struct at the location that I commented in the code.

```
do{
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: yourJSONData!, options: []) as? [Any]

    let firstUser = json?[0] as? [String: Any]
    let id = firstUser?["id"] as? Int
    let firstName = firstUser?["first_name"] as? String
    //etc... for other keys
    let address = firstUser?["address"] as? [String, Any]
    let streetAddress = address?["street_address"] as? String
    let state = address?["state"] as? String
    //etc... create your address struct here and then create the user struct
    dump(firstPerson?["lastName"])
}catch let error{

}
```